# Xamarin Shared project not displaying any content

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've been trying to build a very basic Xamarin.Forms app using the Shared strategy, but I can't get anything to even display on my Android emulator.

I tried to set my MainPage in MainPage.xaml.cs, and then pass it to `MainPage` in App.xaml.cs. I'm not getting any warnings or errors, but my emulator just shows a blank screen. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

All my other code is the boilerplate code generated when you create a new Shared Project. Right now I'm just focusing on the Android project.

**App.xaml\App.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Phoneword
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml\MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

public class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children = {
                new Label {
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    Text = "Test"
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't fully understand it, but apparently there was some other partial somewhere in my app named "MainPage". I changed the MainPage.xaml.cs code to

```
public class NewMainPage : ContentPage
{
    public NewMainPage()
```

and then changed the App.xaml.cs to

```
MainPage = new NewMainPage();
```

and now the content displays. I used Visual Studio to search my app for every instance of "MainPage", and I couldn't find any other uses of that name, so I'm not totally sure why my app thinks there's another partial called that, but at least it works now.